# AVERAGEIF with average in condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007, average, worksheet-function

Is it possible to use AVERAGEIF with an average embedded in the condition? I want to use a formula like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A1:$A10,"<5",B1:B10)
```

but instead of checking A3 to see if it's less than 5 I want to check if `AVERAGE(A1:A3)` is less than 5. For A4 I would want to check `AVERAGE(A2:A4)`.

Right now I am averaging the column first but I have to create a new column each time I do that. I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

*additional info from edit:*
This it to check a person's symptoms vs a drug they are taking, but the symptoms show up three days after the drug is taken. So if in the symptom column the average symptom for three days was less than 5 I want to output the average drug level for three days previous.

Would any of the posted answers provide a solution for that situation?

Comment: So, if AVERAGE(A1:A3) < 5, include A1 to A3?  Is that what you mean?  Can you please provide some sample data with expected results?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED

Now seems quite likely that a relatively simple `=IF(AVERAGE(C2:C4)<5,AVERAGE(B2:B4),"")` may suit:

[image: SO12606558a]

Entered in fourth row (1 for header and 2 & 3 to accumulate 3 days' worth) and copied down. Assumes daily 'readings' and that dosage logically precedes symptoms (though question seems to imply the columns might be the other way around).

Looks to see whether cell immediately to the left + two immediately above that average less than 5 and if so averages the three cells on their immediate left If not, displays nothing `""`. Results rounded to 2 DP.

May require adjustment if the three days of symptoms are not the same three days for dosage.

Comment: Hmmm. You're right that might work. Could I also offset by doing something like changing the ranges? If so that might be a complete solution to my problem.

Comment: Actually this only does one line at a time so I have to create a new column and then average the averages. Then I'd have to create another column with the >5 condition. The cool thing about averageif is that I didn't have to create 2 new columns. Is there a way to combine both of these ideas into an elegant one line equation solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the criterion for including B1 or B2 in the average but it sounds like you want to include B3 if AVERAGE(A1:A3)<5, include B4 if AVERAGE(A2:A4)<5, include B5 if AVERAGE(A3:A5)<5, etc.....

If so, then you can use SUBTOTAL with OFFSET to get an array of 3 cell averages, AVERAGE(A1:A3) up to AVERAGE(A8:A10) and include that in your formula like this:

`=AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(A1:A3,ROW(A3:A10)-ROW(A3),0))<5,B3:B10))`

That's an "array formula" that needs to be confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar